# Hashing a SecureString in C#

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography

In .NET, the [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) type exists to prevent leaking secrets in memory. I want to create a hash from the contents of a SecureString, without putting the contents in memory in a place where I can't delete them. I have come up with the following solution, where I pinvoke the winapi crypto functions to calculate a hash over a BSTR. Does this approach make any sense? Doesn't this put the secret somewhere in memory where I can't delete it?

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool Crypt...(...);

static byte[] CreateHashForSecureString(SecureString ss)
{
    IntPtr hProv = IntPtr.Zero;
    CryptAcquireContext(ref hProv, null, null, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);

    IntPtr hHash = IntPtr.Zero;
    CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA1, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref hHash);

    var bstr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(ss);
    var len = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(bstr, -4);
    CryptHashData(hHash, bstr, len, 0);
    Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(bstr);

    byte[] pbData = new byte[20];
    uint length = (uint)pbData.Length;
    CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, pbData, ref length, 0);

    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);

    return pbData;
}
```

I am aware that error handling is missing. I am also aware that using SecureString is often more hasle than it's worth. I am particularly looking for whether this is the right approach to this problem.

Comment: See also [Hashing a SecureString using Cryptography Next Generation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93111/hashing-a-securestring-using-cryptography-next-generation).

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/11/08/comparing-securestrings-in-dotnet/) and made an [example project](https://github.com/Sjord/CompareSecureStrings) if you want more information on working with SecureStrings.